# "_cvload" reference from.....error

Tags: ios, opencv

I have some problem about an error message

cvload reference from.............

and

```
implicit declaration of function 'cvload' is invalid in C99
```

How can I solve it?(I think it is the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

The second error message means that you are trying to invoke the `cvload` function but you haven't declared it yet. This is probably because the function is actually a member of an object, class or namespace. To know more we would have to see the full declaration of `cvload` and the function that's trying to call it.

Comment: I know what are you talking about this problem,but I don't know what is I lost